# If all sylow subgroups are cyclic, prove that G is solvable

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

I came across a statement which I am unable to prove by myself that if $G$ is a finite group then if all its sylow subgroups are cyclic, prove that G is solvable.
If it has been asked before please give me a link as I could not find it here or please give me the proof. Thanks!

Comment: This is a consequence of [Burnside's transfer theorem](http://groupprops.wiki-site.com/index.php/Burnside%27s_transfer_theorem).

Comment: Isn't there a proof without burnside theorem.

Comment: Any textbook on group theory that introduces the transfer homomorphism should have a proof of this fact. There is also an alternative proof using Frobenius theorem (in a finite group $G$, the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ is a multiple of $\gcd(n, |G|)$. Why do you want to avoid using Burnside's theorem? I think that no "elementary" proof is known.